# What is a ceasefire in Rome: Total War, and what happens if I break it?

Tags: rome-total-war

What is a ceasefire? What will happen if I break it?

Sometimes Gaul comes and asks for a ceasefire and I have nothing to do with it. What benefits can I get from a ceasefire and what would they get?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Rome Total War a lot of factions tend to be weaker. Gaul is certainly one of them especially if you are playing Rome. A ceasefire is essentially saying, "Leave us alone please, we can't take it anymore." You have four options, you can either:

1. Take the ceasfire and not attack them. This choice it stupid and pointless, if you were beating on them you probably want them off the map for good.
2. Ask for a a demand of Denari per year or in a lump sum and leave them alone for a little while. (They will usually eventually break the ceasefire). They will most likely accept the demand at a price of you allowing the ceasefire.
3. Ask for a demand and when all the money is payed compleltey erradicate them like a man.
4. Deny the ceasefire and completley erradicate them.

Personally, Gaul always annoyed me and was always an easy wipe so I would take the ceasefire demand money and then destroy them. Thats the traditional RTW way.

Also, diplomacy in RTW is kind of broken, so there is really no negative connotations to breaking your ceasefire besides of course the faction in question getting mad and maybe their allies. Which Gaul tends to have no allies becasue they are barbaric crazy people.

Diplomacy in RTW is mostly just to beef up your trade routes until you destroy everyone around you. Never let your allies get to powerful though! You will have to take them over eventually if you want to dominate the whole map.

Comment: So it's all about requiring some money for the ceasefire - then, it would be more meaningful to have a `regular tribute` along with a ceasfire.

Comment: Short answer, yes, get something for your acceptance. You are basically letting them live out of mercy. However, it depends on how you feel about the faction really. If you hate them and want them gone anyway, ask them for a tribute or lump sum and they will probably come back to you and say we'll do it if you accept our ceasefire. Accept ceasefire and then destroy them when you have your money.

Comment: In RTW always take from those who are weaker. When at war take men, cities. When accepting ceasefire take money.